# Notepad++ add linebreak after number 1 to 100

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to solve the following problem without success:

I have a document with 100 questions on one line.
In Notepad++ I want to replace each "space | question number | dot | space" and add a linebreak after this, so for example:

1. This is question one 2. This is question one 3. This is question three

To:

This is question one
This is question two
This is question three

I'm new to regex, I managed to create the following: [\s][1-9][0-9][.][\s] but then I'm missing the single digit numbers...

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to show us what you actually tried at least.

Comment: I would probably go with just `\d+\. ([^\d]+)`, and replacing it with `$1\n`. This will not match the leading space, but allow for a trailing space after the question text - that is easier, than trying to match the question text, but leave out the space after it. You can still replace any white space left before the line breaks in a second step, if necessary.

Comment: Use `\s[1-9][0-9]*\.\s` and replace with `$0\r\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this Regex will match only numbers between 1-100 exclusively:

```
\s*([1-9][0-9]?|100)\.\s+
```

while the following will match whatever number of digits regardless of the value:

```
\s*\d+\.\s+
```

- the `\s*` will match zero or more spaces before the number.
- `\d+` matches one or more digits
- `\.` matches the dot, we use the `\` to escape it since it's a special character in regex
- `\s+` matches one or more spaces
- `([1-9][0-9]?|100)` matches any two numbers between 1 and 9 so 1 to 99 and we use the `|` as "OR" to include 100

type your prefered regex in the "Find what" box and `\n` (new line) in the "Replace with" box.

---

you can keep the question number using:

```
\s*(([1-9][0-9]?|100)\.)\s+
```

OR

```
\s*(\d+\.)\s+
```

and replacing it with:

```
\n$1
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer and detailed explanation, it made my regex knowledge a bit better. Think I can figure it out myself from here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :)  happy to help. I suggest you check out regex101.com it helped me a lot

Comment: What should I do when someone answers my question?: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers